# Can I delete it by specifying the number of the numbered Print Cell?

Tags: cellprint, deletecell, cellnumbering

The following is a simple example.

```
i = 0; 
Button["Make Cell", Print[Row[{CellNumbered[ ++i]}]]]
```

I want to give the number to the printed cell and to make a button to delete the cell by selecting the number.

[image]

Can I delete it by specifying the number of the numbered Print Cell?